# Cannot play any file with JMStudio after installing fobs4jmf or jffmpeg

Tags: java, video, jmf

I'm currently developing a multimedia application in Java using Eclipse IDE and JMF API on Windows7. However, I can only play `.midi` and `.mp3` files in my app. This is a bit normal because JMF supports a very limited number of formats and the mp3 plugin must be built in. Strangely enough, JMStudio can't play any file, be it an mp3 or a midi file.

I extended the API by [following the instructions provided](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/f4jmf_first.html), and registering the fobs4jmf plugin with JMStudio as indicated. I also added the necessary jars in the classpath and moved `fobs4jmf.dll` to `Windows/System32`, but the result is still the same -  JMStudio can't play any file I open, nothing happens.

More importantly, JMStudio complains that it can't create a Player for a file I did not even choose on subsequent attempts to open a file. Here's what the errors says the second time I open a file:

> JMStudio Error
>
> Could not create player for file:
>
> nullnullnullnullnullnullnullC:\myFile\MUSIC......\Tu M'en Veux(chui,
>   chui,chui).mp3

The error is exactly the same for any file I open upon failure of the first.
I get the same result if I separately register the jffmpeg plugin (which is actually a jar) with JMStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying Xuggle 5.3 which should at least handle the .mp3 (I think we handle midi too but it's unusual).